# Zenoss - One email alert for multiple events

Tags: monitoring, zenoss

I have written links to Zenoss in some of my apps using the python and xmlrpclib. Events share the same event class and the component begins with the name of the application - ie "AppName - paramaters"

If the application fails, it is common for several alerts to be sent to zenoss.

Is it possible to have Zenoss send only one email for all the events where the component starts with the same AppName, until they have all been cleared?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Zenoss can do this using event mappings. Basically, you tell Zenoss to suppress events from certain "child" sources if a designated "parent" source also have active events.

There's a short explanation on the Zenoss community wiki, here:

- http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-3215.

A common example scenario is remotely monitoring a site with several monitored severs accessible only via a single gateway. If the gateway dies, the servers behind it will be unreachable, and Zenoss will generate events for unresponsive gateway and all of the servers. In this case, the gateway would be a "parent" of the server "children", and an unresponsive-gateway event will cause Zenoss to suppress the unresponsive-server events.